# $\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}2^{n-r}\binom{r}{[\frac{r}{2}]}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

Solve the following summation. $$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}2^{n-r}\binom{r}{[\frac{r}{2}]} $$ where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function. I started by opening the series but everything is ok except GIF function, if I could handle it I believe I could be able to solve the problem. Please someone suggest a way to handle GIF.

Comment: Maybe separate when $r$ is odd or even...

Comment: Is there a reason to suspect this has a good closed form?

Comment: It seems like you can use $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\frac12\binom{2n}n,$ so you should be able to combine the terms when $r$ is odd and when $r$ is even.

Comment: While searching questions, I came across this it’s answer is not available but still it may simplify.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starter. We can split the sum in even and odd part and obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}2^{n-r}\binom{r}{\lceil\frac{r}{2}\rceil}
&=\sum_{r\geq 0}^n\binom{n}{2r}2^{n-2r}\binom{2r}{r}\\
&\qquad+\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{n}{2r+1}2^{n-2r-1}\binom{2r+1}{r+1}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

Here we simplify the first sum of the right-hand side of (1) and show the following is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{n}{2r}2^{n-2r}\binom{2r}{r}=\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

In order to prove (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{r\geq 0}}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{2r}2^{n-2r}\binom{2r}{r}}\\
> &=\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{n}{r}2^{n-2r}\binom{n-r}{n-2r}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{n}{r}2^{n-2r}[z^{n-2r}](1+z)^{n-r}\tag{5}\\
> &=2^n[z^n](1+z)^n\sum_{r\geq 0}\binom{n}{r}\left(\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^r\tag{6}\\
> &=2^n[z^n](1+z)^n\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^n\tag{7}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}[z^n]\left(4(1+z)+z^2\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}[z^n]\left(2+z\right)^{2n}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{2n}{n}}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (2) follows.

*Comment:*

- in (4) we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{n}{2r}\binom{2r}{r}=\frac{n!}{(2r)!(n-2r)!}\,\frac{(2r)!}{r!r!}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{n-2r}
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we apply (3).
- In (6) we do some rearrangements and use $[z^p]z^qA(z)=[z^{p-q}]A(z)$.
- In (7) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (8) we select the coefficient of $z^n$.

*Hint:* The other sum can be similarly simplified and we get finally a nice closed formula for (1).

Comment: Is there a typo at the beginning of the blockquote? Also, $1/z^r/(1+z)^r$ is not a formal power series. Technically speaking you are dealing with a residue here.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Yes thanks, typo corrected. Throughout the derivation we always have a manipulation of a finite sum  only. I don't see the need for residue calculus. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I agree that complex variables most often enters when the sums are infinite (I am not asking that you do use complex variables). But this is not my point -- if you want to work with formal power series you have to make sure that there is a zero principal part (definition of FPS). This is achieved by writing ${n-r\choose r} = {n-r\choose n-2r}.$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks for this clarification. I've revised my answer.

Comment: Looks good. (+1).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [epi163sqrt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4749811/100361) that it is easier to consider odd and even $r$ separately. Here I provide a combinatorial proof of the identity
$$\sum_{r \ge 0}\binom{n}{2r}2^{n - 2r}\binom{2r}{r} = \binom{2n}{n}.$$

As far as we know $\binom{2n}{n}$ is the number of ways to choose from a set of $2n$ elements a subset of $n$ elements. For simplicity we deal with numbers $\{\,1, 2, \ldots, 2n\,\}$. Consider it as $n$ pairs
$$\{\,1, 2n\,\}, \{\,2, 2n - 1\,\}, \ldots, \{\,n, n + 1\,\}.$$
Out of these pairs we select $r$ pairs in which both numbers belong to our $n$ element subset. Then we have also $r$ pairs in which none of two numbers belongs to our $n$ element subset. And in each of the remaining $n - 2r$ pairs exactly one element belongs to our $n$ element subset, either the first or the second one.

Therefore there are $\binom{n}{r}$ ways to select pairs being subsets of $n$ element subset. Then there are $\binom{n - r}{r}$ ways to select pairs non-intersecting with the $n$ element subset. And there are $2^{n - 2r}$ ways to choose for each of the remaining pairs which of two elements belongs to the $n$ element subset. So
$$\binom{2n}{n} = \sum_{r \ge 0}\binom{n}{r}\binom{n - r}{r}2^{n - 2r} = \sum_{r \ge 0}\binom{n}{2r}\binom{2r}{r}2^{n - 2r}.$$
The last equality holds because splitting $n$ pairs into three types can be done both as selecting $r$ pairs of the first type and the selecting $r$ pairs of the second type (what we have done), and as selecting $2r$ pairs of the first and second types together and then selecting $r$ pairs of the first type.

The similar idea works for the odd case if you choose from a set of $2n$ elements a subset of $n + 1$ elements. Also it is possible to combine both and choose from a set of $2n + 1$ elements a subset of $n$ elements. It gives you a full proof without explicit separation into cases.